# SAPUI5: sap.m.TextArea monospace font

Tags: sapui5, textarea, monospace

could you give me a hint how to set the monospace font in the sap.m.TextArea ?
I'm missing something like setDesign( sap.ui.core.Design.Monospace ) in the old sap.ui.commons.TextArea .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an own style file like described here:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796

with content:

```
textarea.sapMInputBaseInner.sapMTextAreaInner {
   font-family: monospace;
}
```